# Definition of nebentypus in $L$-functions.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

In Iwaniec and Kowalski, the term nebentypus is mentioned several times in the book. Every time it seems to just refer to a character $\chi$. Since I don't see the authors defining nebentypus, can anyone give me a concise definition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A modular form is a nice function on the upper half plane that transforms nicely under congruence subgroups of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. It is possible to twist it by a character $\chi$ by letting $\chi$ act on one of the matrix coefficient in the definition. In that case we call the modular form to have nebentype $\chi$. See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_form#Automorphic_factors_and_other_generalizations).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just to make sure, so essentially it is a character but in this context we define it as nebentypus?

Comment: @user73119, yes.